# How do you add spacing between new lines when using objects?

Tags: overleaf, templates, line-spacing

I am using the following code to make a cheat sheet for one of my courses. However, as I continue to add more objects, I notice that on the second line, sometimes the integral signs get too close to the lines directly above. Is there any way to increase the spacing between the lines? I have tried the usual \medbreak but that does not seem to work. I have also tried the {setspace} package to no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.15in,landscape]{geometry} % may exceed print margins
\newcommand{\object}[2]{\textbf{#1:} #2}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} \fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont
    \begin{multicols}{2} 
\object{Current}{$\displaystyle i = \frac{dq}{dt}$} \ 
\object{Charge}{$\displaystyle q = \int_{0}^{t} i \ dt $} \ 
\object{Voltage}{$\displaystyle v = \frac{dw}{dq}$}\ 
\object{Power}{$\displaystyle P  = \frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{dw}{dq}\frac{dq}{dt} = vi$} \ 
\object{Conservation of Energy}{$\displaystyle \sum P = 0$} \ 
\object{Work}{$\displaystyle w = \int_{0}^{t} p \ dt = \int_{0}^{t} vi \ dt$} \ 
\object{Watt-Hours}{$1\text{Wh} = 3600 \ \text{J}$} \ 
\object{Work}{$\displaystyle w = \int_{0}^{t} p \ dt = \int_{0}^{t} vi \ dt$} \ 

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont` is setting the baselineskip (the second number) to something very small. Using `\usepackage[fontsize=8pt]{fontsize}` might work better. Then `\setstretch{3}` from the setspace package should work, but you will need to set it something fairly large (2.5+) for it to help in this case.

Comment: You can alao create a "strut" using `\rule`.  For example, `\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3ex}` will reserve 1ex below the baselines and 2ex above the baseline,  It might be enough just to increase `\lineskip`.

Comment: for 8pt use `\footnotesize` which is 8pt with a far more reasonable 9.5pt baselineskip.